# Extract the amounts(t0, t1) for non-current tick from Uniswap v3 Pool

Tags: uniswap, polygon, uniswapv3

I want to get the amounts of the tokens for a tick range which is higher or lower than the current tick.
For example I have current tick: -282986 with range [-282990, -282980], I want to get the amounts for the tick range [-282980, -282970] (next higher tick range), but I have no success.

I am using this formula:

```
if(sqrtPrice <= sqrtPriceLower){

    amount0 = (liquidity * ((sqrtPriceUpper - sqrtPriceLower) / (sqrtPriceLower * sqrtPriceUpper))) / Math.pow(10, 18);

}else if(sqrtPrice >= sqrtPriceUpper){

    amount1 = (liquidity * ( sqrtPriceUpper - sqrtPriceLower) ) / Math.pow(10, 6);

}else{

    amount0 = (liquidity * ((sqrtPriceUpper - sqrtPrice) / (sqrtPrice * sqrtPriceUpper))) / Math.pow(10, 18);
    amount1 = (liquidity * (sqrtPrice - sqrtPriceLower) ) / Math.pow(10, 6);

}
```

I have read somewhere that for this situations I need to take in calculation the liquidityNet, but I have no idea how to use it, if the information is right.

Someone can help me withe formula for ranges which are out of the current tick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the mathematically way.
To calculate the amounts for tick ranges above/below of current tick range, I have to get the liquidityNet of range(or ranges between current and wanted) and to add/sub to the current liquidity.

Example:

```
Current liquidity: 1000
Current tick: -282986 -> [-282990, -282980] //[tickLower, tickUpper]
Tick space: 10
Wanted range: [-282970, -282960]
-------

Based on tick space, there are 2 ranges from current range to wanted range.
-> r1: [-282980, -282970]
-> r2: [-282970, -282960] (wanted range)

I have to get the liquidityNet of tickLower of r1 and r2:
{-282980, -282970} -> {33, -44}

Because the wanted range is above of the current range, 
we have to add these liquidityNets to the current liquidity.

-> 1000 + 33 +(-44) = 989 (liquidity for the wanted range)

If the wanted range was below, we had to subtract the liquidities.

And now with these values, I can use them in the formula from my question:
calculateAmounts(
  liquidity_wanted_range, 
  current_tick, 
  tick_lower_wanted_range, 
  tick_upper_wanted_range
)

function calculateAmounts(liquidity, tick, tickLower, tickUpper){

  price = Math.pow(1.0001, tick);
  priceLower = Math.pow(1.0001, tickLower);
  priceUpper = Math.pow(1.0001, tickUpper);

  sqrtPrice = Math.sqrt(price);
  sqrtPriceLower = Math.sqrt(priceLower);
  sqrtPriceUpper = Math.sqrt(priceUpper);

  amount0 = 0;
  amount1 = 0;

  if(sqrtPrice <= sqrtPriceLower){

    amount0 = liquidity * ((sqrtPriceUpper - sqrtPriceLower) / (sqrtPriceLower * sqrtPriceUpper));

  }else if(sqrtPrice >= sqrtPriceUpper){

    amount1 = liquidity * ( sqrtPriceUpper - sqrtPriceLower);

  }else{

    amount0 = liquidity * ((sqrtPriceUpper - sqrtPrice) / (sqrtPrice * sqrtPriceUpper));
    amount1 = liquidity * (sqrtPrice - sqrtPriceLower);

  }

  return [amount0, amount1];

}
```

*The used values are random and the code is more like pseudo-code, to present the idea.*

Comment: This looks like JS not Java, you can install and use the @uniswap/v3-sdk specifically the [SqrtPriceMath#getAmount0Delta and SqrtPriceMath#getAmount1Delta](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-sdk/blob/main/src/utils/sqrtPriceMath.ts) in tandem with [TickMath#getSqrtRatioAtTick](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-sdk/blob/main/src/utils/tickMath.ts) to achieve the same result as my solidity contract.

Comment: @MShakeG, the code which I wrote is more like pseudo-code. I translated from my Java code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `@uniswap/v3-core` and `@uniswap/v3-periphery` libraries as shown in the following contract, the uniswap v3 libraries are all open source so feel free to dive into the solidity implementation code.

```
pragma solidity =0.7.6;

import "@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/libraries/TickMath.sol";
import "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/libraries/LiquidityAmounts.sol";

contract UniswapV3Liquidity {

    function getSqrtRatioAtTick(int24 tick) internal pure returns (uint160 sqrtPriceX96) {
        sqrtPriceX96 = TickMath.getSqrtRatioAtTick(tick);
    }

    function getAmountsForLiquidity(
        uint160 sqrtRatioX96,
        uint160 sqrtRatioAX96,
        uint160 sqrtRatioBX96,
        uint128 liquidity
    ) internal pure returns (uint256 amount0, uint256 amount1) {
        (amount0, amount1) = LiquidityAmounts.getAmountsForLiquidity(
            sqrtRatioX96,
            sqrtRatioAX96,
            sqrtRatioBX96,
            liquidity            
        );
    }

    // This seems to be the function you're looking for
    function getAmountsPerUnitOfLiquidity(
        int24 currentTick,
        int24 lowerTick,
        int24 upperTick
    ) external pure returns (uint256 amount0, uint256 amount1) {
        uint160 currentSqrtPriceX96 = getSqrtRatioAtTick(currentTick);
        uint160 lowerSqrtPriceX96 = getSqrtRatioAtTick(lowerTick);
        uint160 upperSqrtPriceX96 = getSqrtRatioAtTick(upperTick);

        (amount0, amount1) = getAmountsForLiquidity(
            currentSqrtPriceX96,
            lowerSqrtPriceX96,
            upperSqrtPriceX96,
            1
        );
    }
}
```

Now to get the `amount{0&1}` per unit of liquidity minted given the current price corresponds exactly with the current tick(this is a close enough approximation in any case i.e. at most 0.01% off) you can call `UniswapV3Liquidity.getAmountsPerUnitOfLiquidity(-282986, -282980, -282970)` which yields the result:

```json
{
  // since the [lowerTick, upperTick] range is above the currentTick, only token0 is required and not token1 
  "amount0": 697,
  "amount1": 0
}
```

Comment: The only problem is that I code my app in Java, where I can't find a lib, so I have to implement by myself.

Comment: These are solidity contracts, so if you can handle big numbers and make a json rpc request you should be ok.